# Jquery, ajax, javascript - getting an element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some ajax onclick stuff that updates this line when the value is selected from the menu:

```
<li id="li_273" data-pricefield="special" data-pricevalue="0" >
```

The intention is to take the that value (data-pricevalue) and then multiple it by the amount that is entered from another input box. Here's my function to try to make that happen:

```
$('#main_body').delegate('#element_240','keyup', function(e){

var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
var element_id = temp[1];

var price = $('#li_273').data("pricevalue"); 

var ordered = $(this).val();

var price_value = price * ordered;

price_value = parseFloat(price_value);
if(isNaN(price_value)){
    price_value = 0;
}

$("#li_273").data("pricevalue",price_value);
calculate_total_payment();
```

});

Except I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'data' of null

It appears as tho my attempt to get the price value out of getElementById isn't correct. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** The code above has been edited from your suggestions and thanks to all. It appears to be working just fine now.

Comment: Note that delegate() is deprecated, use on() instead

Comment: @Christophe true, depending on what version the OP is using.

Comment: @Christophe: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method` `Delegate()` has **not** been marked as deprecated yet. See features marked as deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/ .There is a difference between superseded and deprecated. Features marked as deprecated may get removed in any new version while superseded features are not.

Comment: When I tried to use the .on method I caught errors but the delegate works.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl right, superseded is more correct for now.

Comment: @Christophe: Also, as an interesting side-note. In the later versions of jQuery it doesn't actually matter at all if you are using `delegate`, `live` (deprecated), `bind`, etc.. as those methods have been re-written to use on() anyway. 1.7.1 source for example: `delegate: function( selector, types, data, fn ) {return this.on( types, selector, data, fn);},` or `bind: function( types, data, fn ) {return this.on(types, null, data, fn );},` However, one should always follow the recommendations given by the documentation to prevent any unexpected issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part is wrong:

```
var price = document.getElementById('#li_273').data("pricevalue").val();
```

Instead, you should use jQuery all the way here:

```
var price = $('#li_273').data("pricevalue");
```

Btw, you shouldn't use `.val()` because `.data()` already returns a string. `.val()` is used exclusively for input elements such as `<input>` and `<select>` to name a few.

**Update**

Also, the rest of your code should be something like this:

```
var price_value = parseFloat(price);
if(isNaN(price_value)){
    price_value = 0;
}
```

Comment: When I tried it I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: price_value is not defined

Comment: @MrTechie Well, that's because I didn't spot that other mistake in your code :) updated my answer.

Comment: @Jack, I saw it too - price_val is not price_value. But it's rendering a total of $238.00 for a value of 10 instead of $23.80 if the price is $2.38 per item. Thoughts?

Comment: @MrTechie Who knows? That logic is certainly not part of your posted code.

Comment: Your code has `price_value = parseFloat(price_value);` but never sets `price_value`. Should that be `parseFloat(price)`? And is there supposed to be code that multiplies `price*ordered` to get the total? There's all sorts of things missing in the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

getElementById doesn't return a jQuery object it returns just a normal DOM object.

You can wrap any DOM object in a jQuery call to get it as a jQuery object:

```
 $(document.getElementById("li_273")).data("pricevalue").val();
```

Or better yet just use jQuery

```
 $("#li_273").data("pricevalue").val()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call should be `document.getElementById('li_273')` it's a normal method and doesn't require the hash as jQuery does.

**EDIT** As @kennypu points out you're then using jQuery on a non jQuery object. @Craig has the best solution.

Comment: also to add on, he's mixing native javascript with jQuery. that line should be $('#li_273').data('pricevalue').val();

Answer (score 1):

Your getElementById is wrong with javascript you do not need the `#`, if your using jQuery do it like this instead (Also I removed the .val() because its not needed):

```
$('#main_body').delegate('#element_240','keyup mouseout change', function(e){

    var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
    var element_id = temp[1];

    var price = $('#li_273').data("pricevalue");

    var ordered = $(this).val();

    price_value = parseFloat(price_value);
    if(isNaN(price_value)){
        price_value = 0;
    }

    $("#li_273").data("pricevalue",price_value);
    calculate_total_payment();          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('#li_273').data("pricevalue").val();` should be `jQuery('#li_273').data("pricevalue").val();`

Again the variable `price_value` is not present, I think you mean `price`.

Ex:

```
$('#main_body').delegate('#element_240','keyup mouseout change', function(e){

    var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
    var element_id = temp[1];

    var price = $('#li_273').data("pricevalue").val();

    var ordered = $(this).val();

    var price_value = parseFloat(price);
    if(isNaN(price_value)){
        price_value = 0;
    }

    $("#li_273").data("pricevalue",price_value);
    calculate_total_payment();          
});
```

Comment: correct- tired eyes says that price_val and price_value are not the same. It works but the total price is wrong. It's giving me $238.00 and not $23.80 for a value of 10 selected. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The `document.getElementById('#li_273')` is the problem. The method won't recognize the hash. If you want to get the element ID using that method try `document.getElementById('li_273')` and it will work.

Otherwise use all jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, why are you using document.getElementById instead of `$(...)`? It should be:

```
$('#li_273').data("pricevalue")
```

Note also that the `data()` method is only defined on jQuery objects, not DOM elements. And you don't need to call `val()` after it -- that's for getting the value of form elements.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. jQuery is still new to me and I am trying. Your solution worked - however, if the item is $2.38, and I enter in 10 - it gives me $238.00 and not $23.80. Thoughts?